# Mapping over fetched data into tablecells

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, mapping, jsx

I'm trying to show specific addresses for each tablerow that presents a person. In this code example it's the specific city to show the problem easier.
Here is a snippet of the UI:
[image]

When i press the show addresses button, it should show the specific city for each person, but currently as the image shows, it displays all the cities that are getting fetched from the GraphQL Query.

I know it's not the whole code that is relevant and probably the way i'm using the Popper-component from MUI, but here is full code for the list that contains all the components just in case:

```
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/client';
import SimplePagination from '@components/SimplePagination';
import { SkeletonTableRow } from '@components/SkeletonTable';
import { graphql } from '@gql/gql';
import { PractitionerOrderField } from '@gql/graphql';
import { useDebounce } from '@hooks/useDebounce';
import { usePagination } from '@hooks/usePagination';
import { useTableSort } from '@hooks/useTableSort';
import { Search } from '@mui/icons-material';
import {
  Box,
  Button,
  Grid,
  InputAdornment,
  Popper,
  Table,
  TableBody,
  TableCell,
  TableContainer,
  TableFooter,
  TableHead,
  TableRow,
  TableSortLabel,
  TextField,
  Typography,
} from '@mui/material';
import { useTranslation } from 'next-i18next';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import React from 'react';

const ROWS_PER_PAGE = 20;

const LOADING_ARRAY = [...Array(ROWS_PER_PAGE).keys()];

export const QUERY = graphql(/* GraphQL */ `
  query Practitioners(
    $orderBy: PractitionerOrderInput!
    $pageRef: String
    $pageSize: Int!
    $query: String
  ) {
    practitioners(
      orderBy: $orderBy
      pageRef: $pageRef
      pageSize: $pageSize
      query: $query
    ) {
      nodes {
        bookable
        glnNumber
        id
        locations {
          address {
            city
            country
            lines
            postalCode
          }
          id
        }
        name {
          firstName
          lastName
        }
      }
      pageInfo {
        nextPageRef
        previousPageRef
      }
      totalCount
    }
  }
`);

export function PractitionersList() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const pageRef = router.query.pageRef as string;
  const { orderBy, orderDir, tableSortLabelProps } = useTableSort(
    PractitionerOrderField.Name
  );

  const { data, refetch, loading } = useQuery(QUERY, {
    variables: {
      pageSize: ROWS_PER_PAGE,
      query: '',
      pageRef,
      orderBy: {
        field: orderBy,
        direction: orderDir,
      },
    },
    notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
  });
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState<null | HTMLElement>(null);
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = React.useState('');
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const searchPlaceholder = t('common.search', 'Search...');
  const debouncedSearchTerm = useDebounce(searchTerm);

  const paginationProps = usePagination({
    totalCount: data?.practitioners.totalCount,
    pageInfo: data?.practitioners.pageInfo,
    fetchMore: pageRef => {
      refetch({ pageRef });

      router.replace({
        query: { ...router.query, pageRef },
      });
    },
  });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    refetch({ query: debouncedSearchTerm });
  }, [debouncedSearchTerm, refetch]);

  const handleSearchTerm = React.useCallback(
    (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
    },
    []
  );

  const handleNavigation = React.useCallback(
    (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLTableRowElement, MouseEvent>) => {
      const id = event.currentTarget.dataset.id;
      router.push({
        pathname: `/practitioners/${id}`,
        ...(pageRef && {
          query: {
            pageRef,
          },
        }),
      });
    },
    [pageRef, router]
  );

  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const id = open ? 'simple-popper' : undefined;

  const handleClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    setAnchorEl(anchorEl ? null : event.currentTarget);
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log(data);
  };

  console.log(data?.practitioners.nodes.map(nodes => nodes.locations));

  return (
    <Grid container justifyContent="space-between" spacing={1}>
      <Grid item xs>
        <TextField
          value={searchTerm}
          onChange={handleSearchTerm}
          size="small"
          placeholder={searchPlaceholder}
          InputProps={{
            startAdornment: (
              <InputAdornment position="start">
                <Search />
              </InputAdornment>
            ),
          }}
        />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>
        <Button variant="contained">
          <Link
            href="/medbase"
            style={{ textDecoration: 'none', color: 'inherit' }}>
            {t('common.upload-medbase', 'Upload Medbase')}
          </Link>
        </Button>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <TableContainer>
          <Table>
            <TableHead>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell width="20%">
                  <TableSortLabel
                    {...tableSortLabelProps(PractitionerOrderField.Name)}>
                    {t('common.name', 'Name')}
                  </TableSortLabel>
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell width="20%">
                  <TableSortLabel
                    {...tableSortLabelProps(PractitionerOrderField.Id)}>
                    {t('common.id', 'ID')}
                  </TableSortLabel>
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell width="20%">
                  <TableSortLabel
                    {...tableSortLabelProps(PractitionerOrderField.Identifier)}>
                    {t('common.gln-number', 'GLN Number')}
                  </TableSortLabel>
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell width="20%">
                  <TableSortLabel
                    {...tableSortLabelProps(PractitionerOrderField.Address)}>
                    {t('common.addresses', 'Addresses')}
                  </TableSortLabel>
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell width="20%">
                  {t('common.booking', 'Online Booking')}
                </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>
              {loading
                ? LOADING_ARRAY.map(row => (
                    <SkeletonTableRow columns={5} key={row} />
                  ))
                : data?.practitioners.nodes.map(practitioner => (
                    <TableRow
                      key={practitioner.id}
                      data-id={practitioner.id}
                      onClick={handleNavigation}
                      hover>
                      <TableCell>
                        <Box>
                          {`${practitioner.name?.firstName} ${practitioner.name?.lastName}`}
                        </Box>
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell>{practitioner.id}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell>{practitioner.glnNumber}</TableCell>
                      {practitioner.locations.map(location => (
                        <TableCell key={location.id}>
                          <Button onClick={handleClick}>Show addresses</Button>
                          <Popper id={id} anchorEl={anchorEl} open={open}>
                            <Box
                              sx={{
                                border: 1,
                                bgcolor: 'background.paper',
                              }}>
                              <Typography>{location.address.city}</Typography>
                            </Box>
                          </Popper>
                        </TableCell>
                      ))}
                      <TableCell>
                        {t('practitioner.bookable', '{{ bookable, yesno }}', {
                          bookable: practitioner.bookable,
                        })}
                      </TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                  ))}
            </TableBody>
            <TableFooter>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell colSpan={5}>
                  <SimplePagination
                    {...paginationProps}
                    pageInfo={data?.practitioners.pageInfo}
                  />
                </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableFooter>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are rendering a `Popper` component for each `TableCell` which is sharing the same `open` state. Meaning that clicking on one of the Show addresses would open all of the other `Poppers` as well. A possible solution would be:

1. Have just one `Popper` component and move the `Popper` component outside of your table
2. Add a new state to store the selected location `const [selectedLocation, setSelectedLocation] = useState(null)`
3. Set the selected location state in your `handleClick` function